# How do I get GDB to break on a GLib assertion failure?

Tags: debugging, gdb, glib

Somewhere in a mass of code that I did not write (but I am trying to debug), an assertion fails in the GLib library:

```
(process:31987): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed
```

However, GDB and the code keeps on going. I would like GDB to break where this assertion fails so that I can find out why it is failing. I am not given any more information about where this assertion is. Is there a way to get GDB to break on such a failure?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450001/how-can-i-find-out-where-is-my-code-causing-glib-gobject-critical but this question is clearer, so I'm voting to close that other one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Break on `g_log()`. This covers all cases like `g_warning()`, `g_critical()`, etc.

Comment: The useful gdb commands are: `break g_log if log_level == G_LOG_LEVEL_CRITICAL` and `break g_log if log_level == G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING`

Answer (score 26):

You should add an environment variable like this:

```
G_DEBUG=fatal_warnings gdb ...
```

Comment: `G_DEBUG=fatal-errors` is not working for me, but `G_DEBUG=fatal-warnings` and `G_DEBUG=fatal-criticals` is, also check out [rest of options](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-running.html#G-DEBUG:CAPS).  The line for gdb could be `gdb --args PROGRAM ARG1 ARG2` and then inside gdb issue the commands: `set env G_DEBUG=fatal-criticals` and then `run`