# wxWidgets - wxFilePickerCtrl throws GLib-CRITICAL error

Tags: c++, linux, wxwidgets

I Have a simple Panel initialized with a file picker control

```
wxBoxSizer* top_sizer;
top_sizer = new wxBoxSizer( wxHORIZONTAL );

m_BlenderFile = new wxStaticText( this, wxID_ANY, wxT("Blend File"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
m_BlenderFile->Wrap( -1 );
top_sizer->Add( m_BlenderFile, 0, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 );

m_fileBlend = new wxFilePickerCtrl(
    this, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxT("Select a blender file"), wxT("*.blend"),
    wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxFLP_DEFAULT_STYLE );
top_sizer->Add( m_fileBlend, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 );


m_mainSizer->Add( top_sizer, 1, wxEXPAND, 5 );
```

At the line where I initialize the `FilePickerCtrl`, I get the following output in the console:

```
(bhelper:16553): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_byte_array_remove_range: 
assertion 'index_ + length <= array->len' failed

(bhelper:16553): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_byte_array_remove_range: 
assertion 'index_ + length <= array->len' failed

(bhelper:16553): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_byte_array_remove_range: 
assertion 'index_ + length <= array->len' failed
```

Unfortunately for me, the panel with the file picker is dynamically created by the user, so there could be 10 of these, and each time one is created, the three error lines above pop up.

What am I missing here?

PS: I am using **wxWidgets 3.0.3** on a Linux machine

Comment: What exact version of GTK+ do you have? Did you compile wx yourself or install it from the repository? What happen if you remove wxT() call around your strings?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Do you see the problem on the "file picker" page of the widgets sample, distributed with wxWidgets, or is it specific to your application?

Comment: @Igor I Have Gtk3 installed, No I did not compile wx myself. Removing wxT() doesn't Change anything.

Comment: @VZ. This is specific to my c++ app. I have tried to reproduce with another minimal c++ app and also  wxPython, but can't.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to reproduce it, it's difficult to know where does it come from. As usual, please try running your application under gdb and put breakpoints on `g_log` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785902/how-do-i-get-gdb-to-break-on-a-glib-assertion-failure) for more details), this should give you (and us) at least some idea about where is this coming from.